# Hiding columns in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide multiple columns using VBA based on cell value (this can either be blank or 0). The cells have an array lookup formula also which I think is stopping the functioning of the normal column hiding via VBA. For instance, there are 40 columns, with a maximum of 6 containing a value which has been obtained from another worksheet via a VLookup array. The 6 columns which contain a value can be any of the 40 columns from the VLookup.

Comment: What value is pulled for a blank? `""`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *this can either be blank or 0* For Excel, blank and 0 is the same... unless what you call blank is not a real blank, but a `""` returned by your formula

Comment: Please include your sample data with expected outcome and the code you have tried. That way we can help you pinpoint more exact how to solve your issue.

Comment: what row has the possible values?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started here is a basic macro that will check each cell in a range, and if either of the conditions are met the current column will be hidden. The sheet name and range needs to be changed as needed.

```
Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J20")
        If cel.Value = "0" Or cel.Value = "" Then
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cel
```